# Role of rubber elasticity in the pressure inside a balloon

Tags: pressure, elasticity

I'm just wondering if there's a pressure difference between the atmosphere and the air inside the balloon due to the rubber elasticity. A kind of analogous to the Laplace pressure in soap bubbles.

Comment: Do you think that any force is required to keep the balloon in a stretched position?  If so, can you guess the source of that force?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relationship between balloon size and pressure](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38813/)